# Showing wrong time while changing the format of date

Tags: php, datetime

I'm changing the date format and it shows me wrong format

```
echo $punch_in_time;
// Prints 2013-09-09 11:40:00

echo $new_date = gmdate('D, M-d-Y h:i a',strtotime($punch_in_time)); 
// Prints Mon, Sep-09-2013 09:40 am (Notice the wrong time)
```

I also tried to set the time zone before displaying the time, but no effect.
I don't know why this is happening, it must show my time as `Mon, Sep-09-2013 11:40 am` instead of `Mon, Sep-09-2013 09:40 am`.

Comment: `gmdate` is GMT aware

Comment: You don't say what your time zone is, what code you use to set it or what time zone is `$punch_in_time` supposed to be. It's impossible to say why `09:40 am` is not valid.

Comment: I haven't mentioned here but, I have set my default_time_zone("Asia\Karachi"); thanks anyways for your valuable comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[gmdate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) identical to the [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function except that the time returned is Greenwich Mean Time

use this instead

```
echo $new_date = date('D, M-d-Y h:i a',strtotime($punch_in_time));
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I never know this the Greenwich mean time.

Answer (score 2):

besure to read the description/manual before you use a function.

it says "Format a GMT/UTC date/time" in the description of gmdate(), which means it is assuming the date you entered is in the local time zone (judging from the time difference GMT+2 ?) gmdate then convert it to a date format in GMT+0 time zone.

to make sure the timezone* is consistance between both input and output, use date() instead.

*this will convert the datetime to your local timezone, which might not be what you need.

```
echo $new_date = date('D, M-d-Y h:i a',strtotime($punch_in_time));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggesstion, I m new to php and also for the dates formating. And also thanks for the description. Upvoted